# How to parse functions names from string using javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I'm looking for a reliable way to get function names from a string. The string values can be something like this:

```
let str = 'qwe(); asd();zxc()'
//or
let str = 'qwe("foo");asd(1);zxc();' 
//etc.
```

I want to have an array

```
['qwe', 'asd', 'zxc']
```

I tried `str.split(';')` but how do I get rid of parenthesis and anything they can hold? Is there a regexp that will match all symbols on the left of some other symbol?

Comment: Where is this string coming from?

Comment: What about strings like this? `foo(bar(), baz())` Do they need to be covered too?

Comment: no, function's parameters don't count

Comment: Would it be possible for the parameters to have strings that could contain something that looks like a function? And are you going to allow for space between the function name and the opening `(`?

Comment: No function-like parameters. Space between the function name and the opening `(` is possible.

Comment: Just to be clear, given the criteria, a function-like parameter could be unintentional, something like this... `print("I am a (crazy) coder")` You may want to add some of these details to the question. Maybe a regex would suffice, or maybe you'll need a parser.

Comment: @Andrey It sounds like you're going to need to write a parser. Regular expressions cannot count nested parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this simple regex to find function names in `.match()`

```js
var str = "qwe(); asd();zxc()";
console.log(str.match(/\w+(?=\()/g));
```

Comment: This will give the wrong result if the function calls contain any identifiers in their argument list.

Comment: Thanks, that's very close. What about this: `var str = "qwe(); asd();zxc ()";`?

Comment: @Andrey Your example hasn't such function. However use `\w+\s*(?=\()`

Answer (score 0):

The first case it's fairly simple with regex a simple

> [A-Za-z]\w+

would suffice.

on the second case it's a little bit trickier but maybe supressing the match for this

> "(.*?)"

maybe a possibility